# How to send input from web application to a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am facing some problem when sending the input to webservice.

Here my code :

```
Protected Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Saman.Click

    SamanDB.DataSource = Nothing
    SamanDB.DataBind()

    Dim str As String
    str = TextBox1.Text

   >> Dim copsdataXML As String = myCOPSWeb.Summon(str)

    Dim dsReader As StringReader = New StringReader(copsdataXML)
    Dim DS As DataSet = New DataSet()
    DS.ReadXml(dsReader)

    SamanDB.DataSource = DS  
    SamanDB.DataBind()
End Sub
```

And here the webservice :-

```
public string Summon(string Input1)
{
    SqlDataAdapter dbadapter = null;
    DataSet returnDS = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection(
        "Server=11.2.6.10;"
        + "Database=POLIS;"
        + "User ID=*******;"
        + "Password=*******;"
        + "Trusted_Connection=False;"))
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        string sqlQuery = "select * from SUMMON where ic_no=@Input1";
       
        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        cmd.Connection = dbconn;
        dbadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Input1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Input1;

        dbadapter.Fill(returnDS);
    }

    return returnDS.GetXml();
}
```

I want to send TextBox1.Text as Input1 to webservice.
Here is the exception that I get:-

> SoapException was unhandled by user code.
>
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Parameterized Query '(@Input1 varchar(8000))select * from SUMMON where ic_no=@Input1' expects parameter @Input1, which was not supplied.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: I already edit it, line problem I mark it with ">>"..thanks..:)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Try this order

```
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Input1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Input1;
  dbadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Comment: still not working..if I execute only webservice, its working. but when I try to send input from web application, it thrown that exception. any other suggestion?

Comment: Have you try to set a breakpoint in the webservice and see the value of Input1?

Comment: Yes, already set it, the Input1 is null. That is the problem. Why it cannot send it to webservice. I already check the value of TextBox1.Text is exist. what should I do?

Comment: If it's null then you will get the exception. Check this Q&A http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/sqldataaccess/thread/215c83b3-6bf7-49ea-a6ae-98dc8a2de5fd

Comment: How did you declare the **myCOPSWeb** then?

Comment: This the way how I declare myCOPSWeb..

Dim myCOPSWeb As COPS.Service1 = New COPS.Service1()

Comment: Mr.Evanc, that way also not working. I still get the same exception. I cannot find how to pass the input from web application to webservice..:(..any suggestion please?

Comment: Are you **sure** the value of TextBox1.Text
is not null in `Button5_Click`?

Comment: yes, I already test it and check it using MsgBox after I type the input.Is it necessary to re-add of webservice after modify?

Answer (score 0):

In the Summon method, try replacing this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Input1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Input1;
```

With this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Input1", Input1);
```

Comment: I already did it but the result still same, it thrown the same exception..:(..any other suggestion please..:)